# Usar EntityFrameworkCore.Tools con Maui

Tags: .net, entity-framework, maui

Estoy desarrollando un aplicación con .NET Maui con una base de datos ya creada en PostgreSQL.

El problema que tengo es al intentar usar EntityFrameworkCore.Tools en el proyecto. El objetivo es crear los modelos a partir de la base de datos con EFCore.Tools. Para ello quiero utilizar scaffold.

He intentado diferentes formas de añadirlo y ninguna me ha funcionado. Paso a indicar los pasos para reproducir los problemas y las formas en las que he intentado solucionarlo.

1. Crear proyecto Maui (en mi caso sin Blazor pero creo que es indiferente)
2. Añadir el paquete Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL al proyecto.

Ahora, al añadir EntityFrameworkCore.Tools al proyecto se produce [el error APPX1101](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/1856#issuecomment-1006882973) que se puede solucionar con el comentario enlazado. Sin embargo al intentar crear los modelos con Scaffold a partir de la BD falla con el siguiente mensaje de error:

> targets platform 'Android'. The Entity Framework Core .NET
> Command-line Tools don't support this platform. See
> https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-cli-tfms for more information.

Según pone en el enlace, creo una aplicación de consola, con nombre RunEFCore, en la que incluyo los paquetes de EFCore.Tools y el de PostgreSQL. Sin embargo al crear la dependencia me da dos errores (uno es NU1201 y otro sin código) porque utilizan diferentes `TargetFramework`.

Error NU1201

> El proyecto Maui no es compatible con net6.0
> (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). El proyecto Maui admite:
>
> - net6.0-android31.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
> - net6.0-ios15.4 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
> - net6.0-maccatalyst15.4 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
> - net6.0-windows10.0.19041 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)

Archivo: RunEFCore.csproj

Error

> El proyecto "..\Maui\Maui.csproj" tiene
> "net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst;net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0"
> como destino. No puede hacer referencia a este un proyecto con
> ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0" como destino.  RunEFCore

Archivo: Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    línea: 1805

Aplicación de consola: `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`

Aplicación Maui:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>-->
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

He intentado poner los TargetFramework de una applicación en la otra. Los de Maui en RunEFCore, incluyendo `net6.0`, y de otras formas pero no consigo que funcione. En todas da error o la construccion de los modelos falla.